# How to call a method from another class in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have two classes, the main one and the other is a PopUp. I have a button in the main class that shows the Modal, then after I clicked a button the PopUp will close and, if I click that button I want to execute a function from the other class.

How can I export that method and Imported in the modal class?

This is my method:

```
async getKPIs(year, period) {
      try {
        var payloadData = {
          GroupKey: this.props.data.groupkey,
          FamilyKey: this.props.data.id,
          FiscalYear: year,
          PID: period,
        };
        const response = await axios.post(
          config.kpi.getFiscalYearKPIs,
          JSON.stringify(payloadData)
          , { 'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-api-key': kpiKey } });

        if (response.status !== 200) {
          this.setState({ failed: true });
          return;
        }
        const kpis = response.data['/kpiinput/view/all'].kpiInput.map(kpi => {
          return {
            GROUP_KEY: kpi.GROUP_KEY,
            FAMILY_KEY: kpi.FAMILY_KEY,
            KPI_KEY: kpi.KPI_KEY,
            KPIFISCALYEAR: kpi.KPIFISCALYEAR,
            KPI_NAME: kpi.KPI_NAME,
            KPI_ORDER: kpi.KPI_ORDER,
            UOM_NAME: kpi.UOM_NAME,
            TYPE_NAME: kpi.TYPE_NAME,
            OPERATOR_NAME: kpi.OPERATOR_NAME,
          };
        });

        this.setState({ kpis, failed: false });
        this.getColumns(period);
      } catch (err) {
        this.setState({ failed: true });
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
```

And this is where I want to call it in the modal class, when I close the Swal:

```
 async approveKPI(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var InputValue = this.state.Actualvalue

    if(InputValue){
      try {
      var kpikey = document.getElementById('kpikey').innerText;
      var period = document.getElementById('period').innerText;
      //var typekey = document.getElementById('typekey').innerText;
      var typekey = this.state.CurrentType
      var payloadData = [{
        KPIInputKey: kpikey,
        KPIInputTypeKey: typekey,
        KPIStatus: this.state.derived,
        PID: period,
      }];
      const response = await axios.post(
        config.kpi.approveKPI,
        JSON.stringify(payloadData)
        , { 'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-api-key': kpiKey } });
      if (response.status !== 201) {
        this.setState({ failed: true });
        return;
      } else if (response.status === 201) {
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Data Approved Successfully',
        }).then(function () {
          **//Here I want to call the method from the other class**
        });
      }
      this.setState({ show: false });
    } catch (err) {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Something went Wrong',
        text: 'Try Again',
      }).then(function () {
        //window.location.reload();
      });
      console.log('Error' + err);
      this.setState({ failed: true });
      console.error(err);
    }
    }
    else {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'warning',
        title: 'Input field empty',
        text: 'Please fill input field',
      })
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, welcome to Stack Overflow, is the `modal` a child for the class that has the function in it?

Comment: I dont think so, I am just sending to that modal values from a react-table row. Thanks

Comment: It will be considered as a child if it's inside the `render` method of the component. can you confirm whether it is inside the `render` method of the component that owns the method you want to send to the modal?

Comment: Gotcha, well, in the PopUp class the modal is rendering in that class, in the main one I am just sending the values to the modal with this : `<ApprovePopup row={row} disabled={true} />` every time I clicked on a button.

Comment: So yea, I considered as a child

Answer (score 0):

Alberto, we have figured that the modal is a child for that component, just like the method you want to send.

thus, while rendering your `ApprovePopup` modal, pass the function to it as a property, such like:

`<ApprovePopup row={row} disabled={true} getKPIs={this.getKPIs}/>`

Then, inside the modal's other function `approveKPI`:

```
 async approveKPI(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var InputValue = this.state.Actualvalue;
    const { getKPIs } = this.props; //destructive declaration for getKPIs

    if(InputValue){
      try {
      var kpikey = document.getElementById('kpikey').innerText;
      var period = document.getElementById('period').innerText;
      //var typekey = document.getElementById('typekey').innerText;
      var typekey = this.state.CurrentType
      var payloadData = [{
        KPIInputKey: kpikey,
        KPIInputTypeKey: typekey,
        KPIStatus: this.state.derived,
        PID: period,
      }];
      const response = await axios.post(
        config.kpi.approveKPI,
        JSON.stringify(payloadData)
        , { 'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-api-key': kpiKey } });
      if (response.status !== 201) {
        this.setState({ failed: true });
        return;
      } else if (response.status === 201) {
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Data Approved Successfully',
        }).then(function () {
          **//Here I want to call the method from the other class**
          getKPIs(); //we are using the function we sent as props to the modal
        });
      }
      this.setState({ show: false });
    } catch (err) {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Something went Wrong',
        text: 'Try Again',
      }).then(function () {
        //window.location.reload();
      });
      console.log('Error' + err);
      this.setState({ failed: true });
      console.error(err);
    }
    }
    else {
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'warning',
        title: 'Input field empty',
        text: 'Please fill input field',
      })
    } 
  }
```

Read more about [callbacks](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766) relations between a component and it's children.

Comment: Thank you, Sultan. But I am getting this  "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". Do I need to add the method in the constructor of the modal class?

Comment: You may need to add the approveKPI method to the construction of the modal, but there is no need to do it for the method we are passing down.

Comment: I wonder how it's mistaken `this` while ypur are using it in the same scope.

Comment: Sultan, thank you. But now I am getting "getKPIs is not a function". I am sending two parameters in that function as well, I dont know if that affects

Comment: Are you sure you passed the function as a prop to the modal just as described in the answer? You can pass the arguments just fine.

Comment: Yes, I have this in the main class: `<ApprovePopup row={row} disabled={true} getKPIs={this.getKPIs}/>` and the code changes you wrote.

Comment: is the function `approveKPI` inside your modal's `ApprovePopup` and inside it's scope? such like `class Approve Popup extends React.Component { async approveKPI () .............. }`

Comment: It'll be better for debugging if you have a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/) for these two component, even if you do it with fake functions and fake data.

Comment: Yes, it is inside! Let me do it

Comment: Great, it'll be better.